# JEST with TS - How to do initial configuration and then execute tests from other files?

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm studying about TDD and I'm trying to elaborate a simple test suit for my Node Express API.

I have the following structure:

```
.
└── root/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── services/
    │   │   └── MyService.ts
    │   └── Server.ts
    └── tests/
        ├── services/
        │   └── MyService.spec.ts
        └── SetupTests.spec.ts
```

I would like to make JEST to runs first the "SetupTests.spec.ts" and just after that it should run the "MyService.spec.ts" tests. I have the following code in "SetupTests.spec.ts"

```
import Server from '../src/Server'
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'

let testAxios: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000' })
let testServer: Server = new Server()

beforeAll(() => {  
  return testServer.bootstrap() //It returns the famous 'app.listen()' object
})

afterAll(() => {
  return testServer.shutdown()
})

//I would like to put other *.spec.ts test files here - is this possible? How?
```

But, when running "npx jest", it tries to run "MyService.spec.ts" before running the "SetupTests.spec.ts" and it's always failing because the Server is not listening.

How can I make this work?

Or the best is to put the "beforeAll" and "afterAll" calls in every *.spec.ts file? Is this a good practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to start the server in every test? And for the test setup did you set [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array) ?

Comment: @Fcmam5 Sorry, I still didn't get about how these tests works. I just want to: before starting any test, start the Server, then do the tests, then shutdown the server. Only that

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted by doing the following:

I created 2 files with "**.setup.ts" extensions (without ".spec.ts" or ".test.ts) with the following content:

"env.setup.ts" file:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
console.log("=========== ENV SETUP LOADING ===========")
dotenv.config()
console.log("=========== ENV SETUP LOADED! ===========")
```

"server.setup.ts" file:

```
import Server from '../common/Server'

const server = new Server()

beforeAll(() => {
  console.log("=========== TEST SERVER STARTING ===========")
  server.bootstrap()
  console.log("=========== TEST SERVER STARTED! ===========")
})

afterAll(() => {
  console.log("=========== TEST SERVER STOPPING! ===========")
  server.shutdown()
  console.log("=========== TEST SERVER STOPPED ===========")
})
```

I also used "jest.config.ts" file, pointing to the above setup files:

```
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFiles: [
    "./tests/env.setup.ts"
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "./tests/server.setup.ts"
  ]
}

export default jestConfig
```

To create a test suite for a file, I created a file called "MyServiceClass.test.ts" with the following logic:

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios"

describe("Test my simple api", () => {
  const testAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000' })
  test("my test 1", () => {
    // return axios. [...]
  })

  test("my test 2", () => {
    // return axios. [...]
  })
}
```

And it's now working as I would like!

I posted this question because I didn't find the structure for these initial setup, only everything in 1 file.